# CoreData does not delete from view but it deletes from the Database

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, swift3

Im creating a profile for my app and when Im trying to delete the profile it won't delete from the view if I come back to it, In the other hand if I close the app and open it again the data would be gone. I can see the data been removed from the sqlite Database in my simulator.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showDatePicker()
    showPickerRanks ()
    pickerRank.delegate = self
    pickerRank.dataSource = self
    sideMenus()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate is now UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Profile")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var isEmpty : Bool {
        do {
            let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Profile")
            let count = try context.count(for: request)
            return count == 0 ? true : false
        } catch {
            return true
        }
    }
    if isEmpty == true {
        //Check if there is a Profile
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "NoProfileSegue", sender: nil)
    } else {
        print("No Files")
    }

    print("Database is empty:\(isEmpty)")

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
            if let airmanNameVar = result.value(forKey: "airmanName") as? String {
                PersonName.text = airmanNameVar
            }
            if let airmanRankVar = result.value(forKey: "airmanRank") as? String {
                AirmanRankPicker.text = airmanRankVar
            }
            if let airmanHeigthVar = result.value(forKey: "airmanHeight") as? Double {
                HeightTxtLbl.text = String (airmanHeigthVar)
            }
            if let airmanWeightVar = result.value(forKey: "airmanWeight") as? Int64 {
                weightTxtLbl.text = String (airmanWeightVar)
            }
            if let airmanAFPTScore = result.value(forKey: "airmanLastAFPTScore") as? Double {
                LastAFPTScore.text = String(airmanAFPTScore)
            }
            if let airmanAFPTDateLast = result.value(forKey: "airmanLastAFTPData") as? String {
                LastAFPTDate.text = airmanAFPTDateLast
            }
```

and here is my Delete

```
@IBAction func DeleteBtn(_ sender: Any) {

    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "AF Fitness", message:"By pressing Delete all data would be erase.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    //Create and add the Cancel action
    let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in

    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
    let AgreeAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default) { action -> Void in
        self.resetAllRecords(in: "Profile")

        self.deleteHistory()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "ProfileOn") //Bool Data Type
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        self.AgeGroupSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        self.GenderSeg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "GenderData")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "AgeGroupData")

        self.AirmanRankPicker.text = ""
        self.PersonName.text = ""
        self.weightTxtLbl.text = ""
        self.HeightTxtLbl.text = ""
        self.LastAFPTDate.text = ""
        self.LastAFPTScore.text = ""

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NoProfileSegue", sender: nil)
        // self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NoProfileSegue", sender: nil)
    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(AgreeAction )

     //Present the AlertController
    self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func resetAllRecords(in entity : String) // entity = Your_Entity_Name
{
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate // UIApplication.shared().delegate as! AppDelegate is now UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Profile")

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
    do {
        try context.execute(deleteRequest)
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print ("There was an error")
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: add code of deleteHistory() method

Comment: you do realize that core data removes the data from the database, but updating the view according to the database is your responsibility, don't you? The best core data can do for you is to notify you that something changed in the database. But you need to update the screen manually. Plus, next time do something about the formatting of the code, there are people here that need to read it - not compilers that do not care about it.

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about how CoreData works. Look up some tutorials on how `NSFetchedResultsController` works.

Comment: I understand I don't have much experience with Core Data, @Milan how can I implement that manually. Thanks